# UWP Javascript App - how to use the touch-keyboard when multiple monitors

Tags: javascript, uwp, touch

I'm developing a UWP javascript app using an Aures touch screen device with a second monitor, something like this:

https://images-nitrosell-com.akamaized.net/product_images/14/3282/alt2-aures-nino-epos-system.jpg

The second monitor is integral to the app

The issue is this: Windows 10 will not go into 'tablet' mode while two monitors are connected, and if it's not in tablet mode, I have no way of forcing the tablet-based onscreen keyboard to pop up when inside an input field. I found this:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/message-tablet-mode-isnt-available-while-your/9d6c7525-658b-4cb9-95ae-ec69f854f218

But that gives no resolution to the problem.

I thought I could change the app manually to be touch-based, force it to use touch, with the following code:

```
    const ViewManagement = Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
    const currentView = ViewManagement.UIViewSettings.getForCurrentView();
    currentView.userInteractionMode = ViewManagement.UserInteractionMode.touch;
```

But it turns out `currentView.userInteractionMode` is a read-only field. That code does nothing.

If I can't get this to work, my only recourse will be to build into the app my own custom keyboard -- that's a last-resort though as far as I'm concerned.

I can't find any resources on how to programatically force the keyboard open either. Really pulling a blank here.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an answer

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/83312-turn-off-automatically-show-touch-keyboard-windows-10-a.html

These directions are for enabling the onscreen keyboard as if the computer is in tablet mode, when it's not in tablet mode (I think it only has an effect when (a) you've got a touchscreen monitory and (b) you have no keyboard attached).

OPTION ONE didn't work for me because I couldn't find that setting.

OPTION TWO required a restart but works perfectly after that. In case that website goes down, I'll post option two here:

OPTION TWO gives you a file called `Turn_ON_show_touch_keyboard_.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; Created on: May 1st 2017
; Tutorial: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/83312-turn-off-automatically-show-touch-keyboard-windows-10-a.html


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7]
"EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke"=dword:00000001
```

And to disable it: `Turn_OFF_show_touch_keyboard_.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; Created on: May 1st 2017
; Tutorial: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/83312-turn-off-automatically-show-touch-keyboard-windows-10-a.html


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7]
"EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke"=dword:00000000
```

Just create `Turn_ON_show_touch_keyboard_.reg` on your desktop and double click it, then restart. Might want to restart with keyboard already unattached, not sure if starting the computer with keyboard attached messes anything up.